# Change security settings in Chrome to allow unrestricted Bluetooth access

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I am developing an app that makes use of [Chrome's Bluetooth API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web). The development is highly annoying because everytime I change my code, the page reloads and I need to request permissions to connect to the Bluetooth device again and those permissions can only be granted through a manual process of clicking through an interface

```
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options);
```

will trigger this (sorry the screenshot is german)

[image]

It is not possible to save and restore the permissions for Bluetooth

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'bluetooth'})
```

this is intended to be possible someday but it's a work in progress in the chromium project.

Now I wonder, is it in any way possible to change settings in chrome to loosen a security setting to allow me to just access bluetooth without having be be granted access? Not via JavaScript but by maybe through some setting in Chrome or some `sudo` command I can execute?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the very late response to this question.

I recently implemented a new permissions backend as well as two APIs that will enable previously permitted Bluetooth devices to be used.

The new permissions backend is implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend. The new backend will persist device permissions granted through [`requestDevice()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) until the permission is reset in Site Settings or the Page Info dialog box.

The [`getDevices()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices) and [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) are implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag for Chrome 85.0.4165.0 or greater. The recommended use of these APIs is to use `getDevices()` to retrieve an array of permitted BluetoothDevices and then calling `watchAdvertisements()` on these devices to start a scan. When advertisement packets are detected from the devices, the [`advertisementreceived`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#eventdef-bluetoothdevice-advertisementreceived) Event will be fired on the device that it corresponds to. At this point, the Bluetooth device is in range and can be connected to.

Please give this new feature a try, and file any bugs at https://crbug.com using the Blink>Bluetooth component.

Comment: Wow that is awesome! Thank you so much!